# Loki Proxy wont save settings.

Tags: release-loki, networking

I am trying to change the proxy settings but after I hit apply and close the dialog box it resets the settings back to default after about 10 seconds.

I need the proxy to access the internet on my work network which is a MS AD domain which filters web content by user account. I proxy to a machine I am logged into so I access the web and can update the system and install software.

Freya worked fine.

Comment: I've found a workaround for this issue, see link http://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-without-gui
this is a way to apply a system wide proxy. note that it requires a reboot.

Comment: Same problem here. I installed eOS 0.4 Loki (final version) and you cannot set proxy globally. I think these kind of bugs should not exist, especially when the previous version (Freya) worked fine when it comes to set global proxy.